# Sharepoint views group order

Tags: sharepoint, view

This one should be so simple, I just can't figure it out!
I need to creat a Sharepoint 2010 list view grouped by the number of times a value appears in the list.  I can group by the field name and it displays how many times that value appers, I want to order the groups by  that count.  Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think list view can do that. Check out data view.

See this similar question:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationlegacy/thread/e3173f1f-d4b1-4baf-af0c-91d96c73ca72/

And this one on data views:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-data-view-HA010094804.aspx